# "Need to" as an English Modal

Tags: word-choice, grammar, differences, verbs

In my studies of both theoretical and applied English linguistics, we studied English modals more than once. So a question came up on this site earlier today. I explained that "need to" is a modal. One of the users claimed that it is not.

Question: Is not "need to" a modal?

Comment: Is there an accepted definition of a modal verb?

Comment: Of or denoting the mood of a verb.

Answer (score 2):

The modality of *need* and *dare* (sometimes called "semi-modals") is a matter of [Negative Polarity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf). Their meaning is modal, but their syntax is variable.

Inside the scope of a negative, they can be used as modals; outside it, they can't.
 (Sentences with an asterisk in front are ungrammatical)

- *You need to talk to Bill.  ~ You don't need to talk to Bill.*
- **You need talk to Bill. - You need not talk to Bill.*
- *He dares to protest ~ He doesn't dare (to) protest.*
- **He dare protest ~ He dare not protest.*

As to whether *need to* "is a modal", that depends on

- whether you allow **anything** with a [modal meaning](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf), like *maybe* or *have to*, to be modals
- whether you allow verbs with ***to***, like *have to, need to, dare to,* and *want to* to be modals
- whether you allow verbs that inflect for **tense** (like *dared to* or *needs to*) to be modals

and probably a few other things.

All [modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) are complicated, each modal is unique, and there are simply no general rules about them.